# Powershell lookup RAM information on remote computer and save Partnumbers in to diffent variable

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

I have a simple script that can pull RAM partnumbers from a remote computer and search google for it. But it does not work as intended. If there's only 1 RAM module installed in the remote computer, it works great google opens with the search result for the Partnumber, yay!.

if there are more than 1 RAM module installed in the remote computer, the first Partnumber in the variable gets searched for in Google. The 2'nd, 3'rd, 4'th partnumber gets typed in to Chrome tab 2,3,4 as an address.

How can I get Chrome to search for all Partnumbers via Google?

My script:

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Write Computer Name"

Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -computername $ComputerName
$ToChrome = Read-Host 'Do you want to search Google for the Partnumber(s)? Y Or N'

if ($ToChrome -eq 'Y') {$Partnumber = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -computername $ComputerName | select -expandproperty Partnumber
Start-Process "chrome.exe" ("https://www.google.com/search?q=$Partnumber")}
if ($ToChrome -eq 'n') {Continue}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get multiple objects from `Get-WmiObject`. You need a loop if you want to do something for each of them.

Also, URL-encoding things that you put into a URL is a good idea. and maybe putting it in double-quotes won't hurt.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web   # for [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode()

$ComputerName = Read-Host "Write Computer Name"

$installed_memory = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object Manufacturer,PartNumber,SerialNumber,DeviceLocator,Capacity
$installed_memory | Format-Table -AutoSize

$ToChrome = Read-Host 'Do you want to search Google for the Partnumber(s)? Y Or N'

if ($ToChrome -eq 'Y') {
    $unique_numbers = $installed_memory.Partnumber.Trim() | Sort-Object -Unique
    foreach ($number in $unique_numbers) {
        $query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode('"' + $number + '"')        
        Start-Process chrome.exe "https://www.google.com/search?q=$query"
    }
}
```

---

Powershell has a handy convenience feature: When you have an array of objects, you can query nested properties from all of them in one go.

For example, if there are 4 `Win32_PhysicalMemory` objects in `$installed_memory`, then

```
$installed_memory.Partnumber.Trim()
```

gives you 4 readily trimmed part numbers in a single step.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak, the idea to trim the output to just **Manufacturer,PartNumber,SerialNumber,DeviceLocator,Capacity**,  makes it look so much better :-)

Comment: I get this error twice when I answer 'Y' to look up the partnumbers...**Unable to find type [System.Web.HttpUtility]**.

Comment: @NLB Include this line at the top of your script `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web`

Comment: Thank you, now it works excatly how I want it to :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is because chrome.exe interprets the space between the part numbers as new addresses.

I took the liberty to pimp the script with try&catch,a logfile output and the computername as a parameter so that you can call it as Get-MemoryPropertyAndSearchWithGoogle.ps1 -ComputerName ComputerName1

For my testing I used the attribute DeviceLocator as my PartNumber was empty.

```
#Get-MemoryPropertyAndSearchWithGoogle.ps1
Param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
      [string]$ComputerName
    )
$ErrorPreference='Stop'
$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'
$LogFilePath = "C:\Temp\$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))$($ComputerName)Get-MemoryPropertyAndSearchWithGoogle.log"
[string]$LogFileString = ""
#$Property = "PartNumber"
$Property = "DeviceLocator"
$ErrorExists = $false
$ComputerMemoryObjects = @()
try
  {
    $ComputerMemoryObjects = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $ComputerName -Property *
    $LogFileString += "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"))#INF#Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $($ComputerName)`n"
  }
catch
  {
    $LogFileString += "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"))#ERR#$($error[0].exception.message)`n"
    $ErrorExists = $true
  }
[string]$SearchString = ""
foreach ($SingleComputerMemoryObject in $ComputerMemoryObjects) 
  {
    if ($SearchString)
      {
        $SearchString += "+OR+"
      }
    $SearchString += "$($SingleComputerMemoryObject.$Property)"
  }
$ToChrome = Read-Host 'Do you want to search Google for the Partnumber(s)? Y Or N'
if ($ToChrome -eq 'Y') 
  {
    if ($SearchString)
      {
        try
          {
            Start-Process "chrome.exe" ("https://www.google.com/search?q=$($SearchString)")
            $LogFileString += "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"))#INF#chrome.exe started with searchstring:`"$($SearchString)`"`n"
          }
        catch
          {
            $LogFileString += "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"))#ERR#$($error[0].exception.message)`n"
            $ErrorExists = $true
          }
      }
    else
      {
        $LogFileString += "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"))#INF#`$SearchString is empty`n"
      }
  }
if (!($ErrorExists))
  {
    $LogFileString += "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"))#INF#ScriptCompletedWithoutErrors`n"
  }
$LogFileString | Out-File $LogFilePath
$LogFileString
```